# How do you pass variables between different gradle scripts?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have 2 gradle scripts:

build.gradle and
other.gradle

In my build.gradle I have:
    apply from: 'other.gradle'

```
task callotherscript << {
  thevar = "Thevariableiwanttogetsomeplaceelse"
  dosomecommand
```

In my other.gradle I have:

```
task dosomecommand(type: Exec) {
  executable "someexe"
  args "aa", "<myarg>" + <thevar>, "<intomydir>"
}
```

My question is: How do I get "thevar" from build.gradle so I can use it in other.gradle.

I run: gradle callotherscript

The error message I am seeing is:

> Could not find property 'thevar' on task ':dosomecommand'.

I have looked through the cookbook, and every gradle doc I thought was relevant, and I am just not seeing how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can declare an *extra property*, for example on `project`:

```
ext.foo = "bar"
```

Scripts applied further down can now access the property as `foo`.

It's important to understand that tasks don't call other tasks but *depend* on other tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter. I had been messing around with the "extra property" settings for a few days now. And no matter how many examples I try on the "ExtraPropertiesExtention" page I always end up with: "Could not find property 'myprop' on root project 'myproject'". This is just my evaluation of gradle, it shouldn't be nearly this difficult to pass variables between scripts. I think I will just stay clear of gradle and stick with what works.

Comment: Judging from your code snippet above, you may be setting the property in the wrong phase (execution phase instead of configuration phase). To be successful with Gradle, you'll need to understand these and other core Gradle concepts (e.g. task dependencies). This certainly takes some effort and time.